# Adding an email notification to a WSO2 File Transfer Service that uses the file connector

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-micro-integrator

I have created a file transfer service that uses a file connector. I want an email notification to be sent out when files have been transferred to the directories.
I tried using email connectors and gmail connectors but there are no emails coming through. Is there an easier way to do this without using email or gmail connectors?

The service is done on wso2 integration studio and deployed on wso2 micro integrator 7.1.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt mailto transport to achieve this. Please refer to the documentation here[1].

[1] https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/transport_configurations/configuring-transports/#configuring-the-mailto-transport

Comment: Hi, yes i have tried this but no emails have been sent out or received. The is a part in the article that says "Invoke the proxy service by sending a request. For example use SOAP UI. Check the inbox of your email account, which is configured as the target endpoint. You will receive an email from the email sender that is configured globally in the deployment.toml file." - I am not sure how to invoke a proxy service that's deployed on Micro-integrator 7.1.0. I am new to wso2 development, can you please clarify how to achieve this ?

Comment: A proxy service deployed in MI can be invoked using the URL with the format "http://<ip/hostname>:port/services/<proxy-name>". 
 
The default MI HTTP port is 8290 and HTTPS port is 8253. You can refer 
 https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/proxy_service_examples/Introduction-to-Proxy-Services/

Comment: Note: You can use the mailto transport in APIs as well. The sample in the documentation shows how to use the mailto transport in the mediation. In your use case after the file connector config, add the send/call mediator with the mail endpoint as below;

<send>
    <endpoint>
     <address uri="mailto:targetemail@mail.com"/>
     </endpoint>
</send>

Make sure to enable mailto transport from deployment.toml config as mentioned here https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/transport_configurations/configuring-transports/#configuring-the-mailto-transport